# IE8 HTML5 dynamic content has no style applied with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, angularjs

I am building a website using AngularJs and dozens of JS for fixing IE.

I put data in JSON and different page will pick different JSON data and render it with ng-repeat and ng-view. However, I use HTML5 tag in template files and unsurprisingly IE8 did not style any elements inside ng-view. I am using html5shiv already. What can I do?

I have tried to use div instead of section tags, basically style works. I think the problem is when Angular rendering the view, new HTML5 tags are not wrapped with innerShiv()?

I am done with IE.....

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to make your AngularJS app work in IE 8](http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/08/24/how-to-make-your-angularjs-app-work-in-ie-8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTML5 tag are rendered in <:tag>, if you want to style a section.content like:

```
section.content{
    background-color: red;
}
```

style it like:

```
section.content, \:section.content{
    background-color: red;
}
```

And IE will eventually give the style you want!

Answer (score 0):

Angular documentation has a list for IE specific fixes: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

The main one is to not use the HTML5 style tags like `<ng-view>`, instead do `<div ng-view>`. So far it has not been a problem for me using that guide. I have to support IE8 as well.

Comment: No I am using: <section ng-view class="showExpand" id="mainContent" ng-controller="PageController"></section> to bind view. And even I use div tag, child element style are still blank.